# Why theory at finite temperature is more sensitive to infrared physics than at zero temperature?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, temperature, dimensional-analysis, correlation-functions, thermal-field-theory

At large space-like distances thermal effects modify the behaviour of the correlation function in an essential way:

| Mass | Temperature | $G(0,x)$, $m x \to \infty$ and $x/T \to \infty$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | $\sim \frac{1}{x^2}$ |
| $m$ | 0 | $\sim \frac{\sqrt{m}}{x^{3/2}}e^{-m x}$ |
| 0 | $T$ | $\sim \frac{T}{x}$ |
| $m$ | $T$ | $\sim \frac{T}{x}e^{-m x}$ |

Questions:

1. Why is the theory at finite temperature more sensitive to infrared physics for large space-like separation than at zero temperature?
2. Is there a clear physical meaning?
3. Why does temperature appear to the first power in the numerator? Not a technical explanation, but a physical one.

At large time-like distances correlation decay faster with temperature:

| Mass | Temperature | $G(t,0)$, $m t \to \infty$ and $t/T \to \infty$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | $\sim \frac{1}{t^2}$ |
| $m$ | 0 | $\sim \frac{\sqrt{m}}{t^{3/2}}e^{ i m t}$ |
| 0 | $T$ | $\sim T^2 e^{- 2\pi T t}$ |

1. Why does the temperature correlation function decay faster in the case of time-like distances?
2. Why in this case is the power of temperature in the numerator second and not first, as in the case of space-like separation?

Comment: That seems to be a matter of dimensional analysis.